# Integrating the Dirac delta of a polar rose $\delta(r-\sin(2\theta))$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, dirac-delta

I'm trying to integrate the Dirac delta of the polar rose $r(\theta)=\sin(2\theta)$, i.e. $$\delta(r-\sin(2\theta)).$$
If my reasoning isn't wrong right from the beginning, this should give me the perimeter of the polar rose just like $\delta(r-R)$ integrated in polar coordinates gives me the perimeter of a cirlce with radius $R$. But if I integrate $$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty dr\,r\delta(r-\sin(2\theta))$$
it becomes zero:$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty dr\,r\delta(r-\sin(2\theta))=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\,\sin(2\theta)=0.$$
Of course this is not true and in fact, the perimeter of the polar rose equals $8E(3/4)$, where $E(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind. One thing that also confuses me, is that the similar approach with $\Theta(r-\sin(2\theta))$ (i.e. computing the area of the polar rose) gives the right result: $$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty dr\,r\Theta(r-\sin(2\theta))=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{\sin(2\theta)} dr\,r=\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\,\frac{\sin^2(2\theta)}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
I also tried looking at the cartesian form of the polar rose $(x^2+y^2)^3=4x^2y^2$ and compute the Dirac delta form there, bat in the end it boils down to the same result.

There is probably a problem with my approach, but as of now, I'm unable to see where I'm wrong. I also already looked at the questions [Integrating the Dirac Delta Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989336/integrating-the-dirac-delta-function) and [Compute area of a sphere through a Dirac delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083912/compute-area-of-a-sphere-through-a-dirac-delta?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but had no luck.

Comment: The standard definition of $\delta(g)$ gives $\iint_{\mathbb R^2} \delta(g) \, dx dy = \int_{g = 0} ds/|\nabla g|$, not $\int_{g = 0} ds$. In polar coordinates (and considering that you're allowing negative values of $r$),
$$|\nabla (r - f(\theta))| =
\sqrt {1 + \frac {f'(\theta)^2} {r^2}}, \\
l = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty
 \delta(r - f(\theta)) |\nabla (r - f(\theta))| \, |r| dr d\theta =
\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt {f(\theta)^2 + f'(\theta)^2} \, d\theta.$$

Comment: Thanks! This comment helps a lot. I even think you could have posted it as an answer to my question, as this _is_ the answer. Also the 'trick' with extending the [0,$\infty$) intervall to ($-\infty$,$\infty$) via introducing the absolute value of $r$ is quite interesting.